# Azure AD B2C - Assigning User to Application Role

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am following this Microsoft video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPyjneHE9HM to assign a user to an app role. However,  the item "Users and Groups" under the "Manage" subsection is missing on my screen (check video after 31:25 mins). Has the process changed or has the menu item been relocated? I was able to do this 2 months ago in the same directory subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same experience when the App Registration is set to ‘Public Client’ = Yes. If I set it back to No temporarily, I get the Users and Groups option again, can assign users, and can then switch it back to Yes to allow the ROPC flow. If you don’t need the ROPC flow, then set this to No and you should be good.

What I don’t understand is why this option isn’t available for public clients. In my case, that’s the only time I want to limit app registration usage to certain users because I don’t want my whole user base using ROPC.

Comment: That is precisely correct. Very strange though but I am better off toggling between Yes and No for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!